# How do I insert a C# object in postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a legacy code which I'm trying to change. This legacy code stores and retrieves data from local storage. I'm trying to change it to save data, specifically c# classes, in a postgres database.
The way the legacy code stores data is this:

```
FileSerializer.Serialize<T>(filename, instance);
```

I know how to INSERT INTO a serializable java object in postgres but I can't find a tutorial on how to do it with a c# object.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: For the love of everything holy, please use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) (if you're working with .NET Framework), or [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) (if you're with .NET Core). There are great tutorials and a lot of documentation out there for both

Comment: Newbie question, but how do I determine which framework I'm working? Properties show <target framework> option as <.NET framework 4.6> so it shouldn't be .NET CORE right?

Comment: You can right click on the project in the solution explorer of Visual Studio and select "Properties", there you have a drop down titled "Target Framework". If for some reason you're not using Visual Studio you should check out the list of [supported target framework monikers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks).

Comment: It's .NET framework 4.6 so I'll check the Entity Framework which you've mentioned.

Comment: Since you mentioned you're working with PostgreSQL database, check out this nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/

Comment: Yes, thank you, although I already have this. Now I need to learn how to connect my existing database to my project and insert objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/) as it supports ORM and postgres.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with [NEntityDb](https://nentitydb.com). You can find samples of how to insert objects [here](https://nentitydb.com/pages/docs/save-data/insert-data.html).

```
using (DbInstance dbInstance = new DbInstance()) 
{    
    int rowsAffected = dbInstance.NonQueryOf<Customer>(new Customer
    {
        FirstName = "Clair",
        LastName = "Guiet",
        TaxCode = "3720045188",
        Email = "cguiet@gov.uk",
        BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 4, 15),
        Points = 10
    })
    .Insert()
    .RowsAffected;
}
```